# Icon not constantly updated in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

Flutter is trying to keep the icon of the listtile element updated but when you click on the icon of the same element it is not updated, when you click on the icon of a different element it is updated.
Gif file has videodo, the icon of the same element does not change a second time.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLJ2e.gif

```
 import 'dart:developer';
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
 import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';

class MusicPlayerController extends ChangeNotifier {
    final player = AudioPlayer();


   int  _playingIndex = -1;

   MusicPlayerController() {
       player.playerStateStream.listen((state) {
      if (state.processingState == ProcessingState.completed) {
        _playingIndex +=1;
         notifyListeners(); 
      }
   });
  }


 Future<void> playOrPause(int index, String uri) async {

    if (index == _playingIndex) {
      if (player.playing){
        player.stop();
        icon(index);
       }
   else{
     player.play();
   
    }
    notifyListeners(); //Adding this solved the problem
   } else {
     player.setAudioSource(AudioSource.uri(Uri.parse(uri)));
      player.play();
     _playingIndex = index;
       notifyListeners(); 
    }
   }

 Icon icon(int index) {

     if (index == _playingIndex) { 

 
      return player.playing ?  Icon(Icons.pause_circle) :
       Icon(Icons.play_circle_outline_outlined) ;
  
    } else {
        return Icon(Icons.play_circle_outline_outlined);
    }
   }
  }




     return ListTile(
              title: ,
              subtitle:,
              leading,
              trailing:Consumer<MusicPlayerController>(
                builder: (context, controller, child) {
                    
               return IconButton(
                        
                         iconSize: 30,
                         onPressed: () {  
                                             
              controller.playOrPause(index,(provider.musicList[index].uri).toString());
                           
                         },
                         icon:  controller.icon(index),
                      );
                },
              ) 
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create the ListTile, you determine the icon based on the current state.  When you click on a tile, you change that state  (you change _playingIndex).  However, you don't tell Flutter that the state is changed.  So Flutter is not going to update the Icon widget.

For example, if you `playOrPause` method always ended in something like:

```
setState(() { /* we want the icon to changed. */ });
```

Then Flutter knows the widget's state has changed and it will re-render everything - and the icon will update.

You can learn more about state management [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/intro).

Comment: How can I put the icon in setstate?

Comment: You don't need to.  Did you try the code?

Comment: icon is not included in set state

Comment: You don't need to. Did you try the code?   
Read up on state management - I really do suggest you do this.

Comment: problem solved notifyListeners(); I left something missing somewhere